# How to update the application built by electron-packager?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I have `main.ts` in which there is such a field

```
win.loadURL('https://example.com').then();
```

this thing allows you to update the electron application via `github-release`

but there is one thing! if I change something `main.ts`

then I have to build everything all over again and make a new exe

there are options for how to automate this?